# How to better work with wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Some questions. What option is much better, create a lot of windows in project to move from one window, to another. Or, work in one window and just when I need to move from login window for example, just clear the Grid and Load another Grid with their controls, objects etc. Accept any tips, thanks

Comment: You may find Caliburn Micro navigation useful http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/

Comment: There's not really a right or wrong answer for this, because it depends on your own design and preferences.

Comment: @wiero How is that plug relevant in any way to the question asked?

Comment: One main window with modal dialogs is generally seen now as the more user-friendly way to do it. A "modal" dialog is one that disables the parent while the dialog is open. MessageBox, for example, or the Open and Save File dialogs, are usually modal. And you can create your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like to create just one Window, put a top menu on it, and a ContentPresenter in the center of the window. Then, I create some UserControls that are the "pages" of the app. On the top menu, handle the click events. For example, on the "User Profile" menu, open up the UserProfile page:

```
contentControl.Content = new UserProfile();
```

where UserProfile is the UserControl you created.

Also, read about [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). If you come from a WindowsForms/WebForms world, then it you be confusing in the beginning, but if you have time to learn, it does worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check with your users.

Flow from one window to another is **wizard dialog**. You can be sure that all steps are taken. But expert users that may be annoying.

On the other side showing all options in main window may be overwhelming for novice users and excellent for experts :)